# Installing GCC4.8.5 on CentOS8 using GCC8.5

Tags: centos, configuration, make, gcc, dependencies

I am trying to install GCC4.8.5 under CentOS 8 using GCC 8.5. Here's what I did

Get the compiler and its dependencies

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz
tar zxf gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.8.5
./contrib/download_prerequisites
```

Patch the file as described here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=ec1cc0263f156f70693a62cf17b254a0029f4852

Configure and make

```
mkdir gcc-build-4.8.5
cd gcc-build-4.8.5
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc4.8.5 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
make
```

The whole thing fails on the MAKE step with the following error:

```
checking how to run the C preprocessor... (cached) /BioDB2/wgf/software/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-build-4.8.5/./gcc/xgcc -B/BioDB2/wgf/software/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-build-4.8.5/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/gcc4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/gcc4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/gcc4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/gcc4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -E
configure: error: in `/BioDB2/wgf/software/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-build-4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/BioDB2/wgf/software/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-build-4.8.5/./gcc/xgcc -B/BioDB2/wgf/software/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-build-4.8.5/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/gcc4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/gcc4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/gcc4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/gcc4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -E" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
make[2]: *** [Makefile:17330: configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/BioDB2/wgf/software/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-build-4.8.5'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21493: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/BioDB2/wgf/software/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-build-4.8.5'
make: *** [Makefile:892: all] Error 2
```

I checked the config.log

```
configure:4939: checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
configure:4956: g++ -o conftest -g -O2   -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc conftest.cpp  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4956: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
/* end confdefs.h.  */
#if (__GNUC__ < 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5)
#error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
```

then I use the command to install the dependencies:

```
yum install -y libstdc++*
```

and after that, I reconfigure and make,but it still failed and the error is same as before

Could you help me to figure how to overcome this issue? Thanks

Comment: Note the suggestion `See `config.log' for more details`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The config.log file said `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++`, then I install the lib using `yum install -y libstdc++*`,but it still failed and the error is same as before@mashuptwice

Comment: do you have g++ compiler instlled?

Comment: yes, when I use `yum install gcc-c++` , it said `Package gcc-c++-8.5.0-4.el8_5.x86_64 is already installed.` `Dependencies resolved.` `Nothing to do.` `Complete!`@Vaibhav.c